# Filter array of objects where one field in object is array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

```
 data:[
        {
           id:1,
           tags:['TagA','TagB','TagC']
         },
         {
           id:2,
           tags:['TagB','TagD']
         },
         {
            id:3,
            tags:['tagE','tagC']
         }
      ]

filterCondition:{tags:['TagA','TagB']}

Expected Output: [
                   {
                     id:1,
                     tags:['TagA','TagB','TagC']
                   },
                   {
                     id:2,
                     tags:['TagB','TagD']
                   }
                 ]
```

Is there a possible way to achieve this in typescript using filter method?
   It is possible when tags field is not an array but when it is in array the 
   code breaks.

I tried but it fails:

```
   data.filter(o => Object.keys(filterCondition).every(k => filterCondition[k].some(f => o[k] === f)));
```

Comment: typescript is superset of js, so js solution will work because it is js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `filter` and `includes`

```js
const data = [{id:1,tags:['TagA','TagB','TagC']},{id:2,tags:['TagB','TagD']},{id:3,tags:['tagE','tagC']}];
      
const filterData = tag => data.filter(d => tag.some(t => d.tags.includes(t)));

console.log(filterData(['TagA', 'TagB']));
```

Little edit in the form of conditionArray mentioned:

```
    let filterArray={tags:['TagA','TagB']}

    const data = [{id:1,tags:['TagA','TagB','TagC']},{id:2,tags:['TagB','TagD']},{id:3,tags:['tagE','tagC']}];

    output= data.filter(o => Object.keys(filterArray).every(d => filterArray[d].some(t => o[d].includes(t))));
```

Comment: I want to filter it based on 'filterCondition' array, hence includes wont work when filterCondition:{tags:['tagA','tagB']}

Comment: it is based on that array as you described in question, please explain what you mean and give example

Comment: Artyom Amiryan ,please see the edited example. If any of the tags in the condition array is present in the object, then that object should be there in the ouput

Comment: @RishabhBharatGada I have updated my example, please check if is it what you need ?

Answer (score 2):

```js
const s = {
  data: [{
      id: 1,
      tags: ['TagA', 'TagB', 'TagC']
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      tags: ['TagB', 'TagD']
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      tags: ['tagE', 'tagC']
    }
  ],
  filterCondition: {
    tags: ['TagA', 'TagB']
  }
};

console.log(s.data.filter(a => s.filterCondition.tags

  .some(s => a.tags.join(',').includes(s))));
```